# How to add the 'Any Type' questionmark in JavaPoet?

Tags: java, code-generation, javapoet

I'm generating code with JavaPoet.

Somewhere in the generated code I want to add a method which has the following argument.

```
...
    public B someMethod(final AbstractObjectBuilder<Persoon,?> builder) {
       ...
    }
...
```

So my JavaPoet code should look something like this

```
    //This does not compile, since I don't know what to put as last argument (questionmark)
ParameterizedTypeName parameterizedTypeName = ParameterizedTypeName.get(AbstractObjectBuilder.class, propertyType,?);

ParameterSpec parameterSpec = ParameterSpec.builder(parameterizedTypeName, name+"Builder", Modifier.FINAL).build();

MethodSpec modMethod = MethodSpec.methodBuilder(name)
                        .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                        .addParameter(parameterSpec)
                        .returns(TypeVariableName.get("B"));
...
```

Comment: you can use `<Persoon, ? extends <any_class_name or Object>>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Foo<?>` is a short form of `Foo<? extends Object>`. Use `WildcardTypeName` for this.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: This: ParameterizedTypeName.get(ClassName.get(Class.class), WildcardTypeName.subtypeOf(Object.class)

gives a Class<?>.